# Word for discrimination on the basis of domicile

Tags: single-word-requests

A person belongs to a different country than the one she is currently in. She is clearly a *foreigner*/*alien*. But what is the single word for the discrimination faced by her when the natives of this country constantly call her a *foreigner* in order to point out that she does not belong here?

In other words, what's the word for domicile based discrimination?

Comment: *domicile* means where you live - as in *house* not country.

Comment: Please read the related [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159908/if-a-person-holds-prejudice-against-people-because-of-their-nationality-would-t) and see if it answers your question. There are many types of biases and prejudices. You need to be more specific on when and how you use would the word.

Comment: @Jim: What you are saying is mentioned in my dictionary as "chiefly US" definition. The primary definition is given as: *the country that a person treats as their permanent home, or lives in and has a substantial connection with.* Ex. His wife has a domicile of origin in Germany.

Comment: @Rathony: I'm talking about the case when a native person would, in a way, taunt about the other person being a foreigner. Doesn't matter which country these foreigners belong to. This is not race or country based discrimination rather it's a discrimination against anyone who is a citizen of another country.

Comment: Hmm. I've never heard of that usage, and in checking in 4 different dictionaries that I have, none of them mention it. (American Heritage, Collins, Random House, Merriam Webster)

Comment: Then, xenophobia seems to be the word you are looking for.

Comment: @Jim: I have a MacBook and its dictionary says so.

Comment: You could also try *alienation* ... ;-)

Comment: @Jim: Sounds close. A word that ends with 'ism' would be a bull's eye.

Comment: @Rathony: Phobia is fear. The other person does not fear the foreigner. He hates them and his behavior towards them is discriminatory.

Comment: Phobia doesn't necessarily mean "fear". Not always. Look up the dictionary. It means "hatred" in [Xenophobia](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=xenophobia&searchmode=none). Dictionaries are there to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As close as I can come is

> **nativism**, *n*.
>   1. a. Chiefly U.S. The attitude, practice, or policy of protecting the interests of native-born or existing inhabitants against those of immigrants ....

["nativism, n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125308?redirectedFrom=nativism (accessed November 21, 2015).]

This term, 'nativism', has a number of historical and contemporary uses that may conflict with or cause dissonance for any use in the simple sense of

> discrimination against a person because that person is from another country.

Those conflicting uses include senses of the term bearing on cultural anthropology (contemporary), the US Native American party (historical), the philosophical notion that some knowledge may be innate (contemporary), and specialized uses in psychology and linguistics (contemporary).

Comment: Definitely like this answer.

Comment: I think the only thing against this word is that it is not *perceived* as bad as racism. Otherwise nativism is a discrimination, just like racism.

Answer (score 2):

I would also include "othering" but even this term excludes the aspect of domicile.

To "other" means to exclude someone from admittance or membership from a group by highlighting differences of that person excluded.

Why not create a term for what you seek. Many scholars do.

I nominate "xenocentric othering" or "citizenship othering" .

Comment: Really liked your thought about creating a new term. After all we only are the creator of language and when lacking a good word, we shouldn't hesitate to add a new one.

Comment: I agree entirely. To often we defer to the authority of language as sacrosanct.

Answer (score 1):

[Xenophobia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/xenophobia) - Intense or irrational dislike or fear of people from other countries.

Comment: You could use this [link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=xenophobia&searchmode=none) in your answer that explains etymology of the word.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not know of a single word that would satisfactorily answer your question, the term 'xenophobic prejudice.' The word prejudice could be replaced with bias, bigotry, or intolerance.

The following definitions all come from the Merriam Webster dictionary.

Xenophobia -
Fear and hatred of strangers or foreigners or of anything that is strange or foreign.

Prejudice - 
1:  injury or damage resulting from some judgment or action of another in disregard of one's rights; especially :  detriment to one's legal rights or claims

2 a (1) :  preconceived judgment or opinion (2) :  an adverse opinion or leaning formed without just grounds or before sufficient knowledge
b :  an instance of such judgment or opinion
c :  an irrational attitude of hostility directed against an individual, a group, a race, or their supposed characteristics

Bias - 
a :  bent, tendency
b :  an inclination of temperament or outlook; especially :  a personal and sometimes unreasoned judgment :  prejudice
c :  an instance of such prejudice
d (1) :  deviation of the expected value of a statistical estimate from the quantity it estimates (2) :  systematic error introduced into sampling or testing by selecting or encouraging one outcome or answer over others

Bigot - 
:  a person who is obstinately or intolerantly devoted to his or her own opinions and prejudices; especially :  one who regards or treats the members of a group (as a racial or ethnic group) with hatred and intolerance

Intolerant -
1 unable or unwilling to endure
2a :  unwilling to grant equal freedom of expression especially in religious matters
b :  unwilling to grant or share social, political, or professional rights :  bigoted

Answer (score 1):

Xenophobia is much too specific, I think. If you're looking for a milder term (when the offender doesn't mean to insult anyone), you might want to look at this Wikipedia article on something called the Microaggression Theory. The theory was expanded a bit recently to include cases similar to what you have in mind:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microaggression_theory